# Return all available mappings on RequestMethod GET

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I'm learning about spring boot and having a REST Server with JPA.
For my RestControllers, I wanted to have the behavior on the base page that when someone goes to the base page they would be able to see all the available RequestMappings under the base page.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/food")
public class FoodRestController {

@RequestMapping(value = "/all", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public Iterable<Food> printAllFoods() {
    return foodRepository.findAll();
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<?> addFood(@RequestBody Food f) {
    foodRepository.save(f);

    HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    return new ResponseEntity<Food>(f, httpHeaders, HttpStatus.CREATED);
}
```

So for the above going to "localhost:8080/food" would give a page showing something like not a valid endpoint, possible endpoints are localhost:8080/food/all or localhost:8080/food/add.
I could just have a RequestMapping with GET and return it as a body but it would be a manually typed response. Wanted to see if Spring offers anything like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SpringBoot Actuator already has a functionality that does something like this.  Add a dependency on the [SpringBoot Actuator](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#production-ready-enabling), start up your application and point your browser to:

> http://[yourHostAndPort]/mappings

This will produce something like the following (assuming JSON), which contains *ALL* mappings that are a part of your project (Spring endpoints too!).

```
{
  ...
    "{[/refresh],methods=[POST],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}": {
        "bean": "endpointHandlerMapping",
        "method": "public java.lang.Object org.springframework.cloud.endpoint.GenericPostableMvcEndpoint.invoke()"
    },
    "{[/restart],methods=[POST],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}": {
        "bean": "endpointHandlerMapping",
        "method": "public java.lang.Object org.springframework.cloud.context.restart.RestartMvcEndpoint.invoke()"
    },
    "{[/configprops],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}": {
        "bean": "endpointHandlerMapping",
        "method": "public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()"
    },
    "{[/env],methods=[POST],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}": {
        "bean": "endpointHandlerMapping",
        "method": "public java.lang.Object org.springframework.cloud.context.environment.EnvironmentManagerMvcEndpoint.value(java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>)"
    },
  ...
}
```

This snippet shows a small handful of the mappings that are available from some other Actuator endpoints.

I understand that your requirements are a bit different, so if this setup isn't exactly what you need, you should be able to create your own endpoint(s) that do something similar, just by browsing the [SpringBoot Actuator source code](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-actuator).  The specific file that does the majority of the work for the *mappings* endpoint is [`org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.RequestMappingEndpoint.java`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-actuator/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/actuate/endpoint/RequestMappingEndpoint.java).

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [Swagger](http://swagger.io/) . It is actually a documentation framework. It also builds around a beautiful UI to try out the APIs that are available along with the documentation.